# Display access query output in a text file - notepad

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I display the outout of a query in a notepad on button click in access?

I have a button "View Query Output" in access. I want to be able to display the ouput in a notepad file. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DoCmd.TransferText` to save the output to a textfile and `FollowHyperlink` to open the file.

Comment: Would you happen to know why using the following command deletes my file: TestFile.txt?
Dim Test_File as string
Test_File = "C:\Users\Documents\TestFile.txt"
DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed, "Test_Specification", "Test_View", Test_File